# Can anyone direct me toward a site where I can find a list of block types and names that I can use?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, layout, blocks

Can anyone direct me toward a site where I can find a list of block types and names that I can use or any useful resources? I tried going to *System > Configuration > Developer > Debug* to activate the path hints, but this option was not available (only 'Profiler' appears, there is no 'Template Path Hints' or Add Block Names to Hints'). I'm running Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be in Default configuration scope(check this at top left side)that is why you are not able to see template and block hints options. Change the scope to Main Website and you will be able to see the template and block hints option.

Good Luck!:)

Answer (score 1):

Block types are endless and can be anything. So we cannot categorize them and list them in a post.

There are blocks which are using in every page in Magento and there are blocks which will be rarely used or even not used in Magento. Blocks names varies according to the module configuration and block defintion. That means blocks which are generating by individual modules are unique and different.

As I said, there are some blocks which are regularly used. For an example `content`, `left`, `right` blocks (they are also known as structural blocks since they acts as parent blocks for different section of the page layout). You can find default structural blocks in `page.xml`. Layout update xml files other than `page.xml` holds page specific blocks. They are endless.

You can find some regularly used ***[block type list in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633307/understanding-magento-block-and-block-type)***. For detailed information about Magento blocks, ***[you can refer this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates)***